# Memsql, Is it possible to add more leaf nodes on the same host machine?

Tags: database, cluster-computing, singlestore

I installed a functional test with Memsql on a machine with an aggregation node on port 3307 and a leaf node 3306.  As queries being ran, there might be additional cpu available.  Hence, is it possible to add more leaf nodes on the same machine to take advantages of available resource?

I tried to add leaf node using the UI on port 9000, and receive this message:

```
Cannot use web ui to deploy additional leaf nodes to hosts which already have at least one leaf node.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, web ui doesn't support adding more leaves on the same machine. However, you can add more leaves on the same machine via command line:

```
memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role leaf --port 9000
```

While web-ui cannot add a new leaf, it will be able to manage it once it is added from the command line.